# Adding number to multiple cells in google sheets - without dragging corner or copying background color

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried to figure out multiple ways to do this. It seems like it should be simple enough but I haven't been able to figure out how to select multiple cells to fill them with the same number - without changing a preexisting background color that I have across some cells.

If I do the usual select the cell, drag the corner routine, I end up copying the background color in unintentional ways.

I literally just need the same number (.25) assigned to almost every cell. [image]

Answer (score 1):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(RANDARRAY(COUNTA(A:A),COUNTA(1:1))), 0.25, ""))
```

[image]

**Explanation**

`COUNTA(A:A)` is the number of columns in the range `A:A`.
`COUNTA(1:1)` is the number of rows in the range `1:1` the "header". 
You can replace it with hard coded number

**Example:** `12` columns and `10` rows.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISNUMBER(RANDARRAY(12,10)), 0.25, ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(SEQUENCE(5; 6; 1; 1)*0.25)
```

where 5 is row and 6 is column

Comment: update it to this `=INDEX(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A), COUNTA(1:1), 1, 0)*0.25)`